# Remove switch off 'delay' from a Solid State Relay Board

Tags: capacitor, switches, relay, inductor, solid-state-relay

I'm switching audio signals (line level) with a solid state relay board (Keyes - 8x Q3MB-202P), but when I switch off one channel, it takes some milliseconds (maybe around 500ms to 2 seconds) to really stop the signal flow. I believe this happens due to either a capacitor or an inductor (I think it's an inductor) that's in the board, so I was wondering if I could remove (unsolder) one of these components from the board and make the switching off more precise.

I don't have an individual piece of a Q3MB-202P, but I believe this wouldn't happen with the individual piece. This is probably caused by the board circuitry, which does that for integrating LEDs or for some safety reasons which I don't mind sacrificing. I couldn't find a schematics of this board, but probably someone will know by the picture.

Attached are pictures of the board. What I have referred as inductor is the green piece (F), but I'm not sure if I'm right. In this piece it's also written 2A (or 2AE, it's not very legible).

[image]
[image]

**Note 1:** the reason I'm switching signals with Solid State Relays is because I need low resistance. I'm avoiding using a IC (like 4066) as it has too much resistance for my audio signals and then the sound is too quiet.

**Note 2:** I don't want to use a mechanical relay to avoid the click noise.

**Note 3:** I don't have individual pieces of Solid State Relays (Q3MB-202P) and I don't have the time to buy them now. I need to sort out this problem quickly for a project as the deadline is in 3 days.

I really appreciate any help!!! Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but solid state relays are simply the wrong tool to switch audio. Don't ask us to fix a circuit that is broken by principle. Your's broken by principle, because these SSRs come with a zero-crossing detection, which is probably what causes your delay. What you say about "too high resistance" makes no sense for line-level signals –  the receiving end's impedance would typically be sooo much larger, that a small series resistance doesn't make *any* difference. But: SSRs definitely weren't designed for audio bandwidths.So, your approach is based on false claims and the wrong components.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you comment. The switch works perfectly for what I'm doing. I have everything working in terms of audio.  What I mean with high resistance I think I'm right, as I tested before with a 4066 and the sound is too quiet.

Comment: And if you are right about the zero crossing, which I still think is the inductor or capacitor, do you have any suggestion for a 8 channel switch, besides criticism?

Comment: Then your "line-level" signal is not what audio techs would call line-level. There's dedicated audio switch ICs (many!). Use these. There's not a single inductor nor a single capacitor in your photos.

Comment: The audio signal is generated by an Arduino using a library that synthesises sound through PWM. It's not amplified and the output is a 1W speaker. So I assumed this is line level.

Comment: And when I tried to find an audio switch for this, it seems that everyone suggests the 4066, which makes my audio very quiet compared to relays. I bet that if I use the individual piece it will work fine.

Comment: "you bet" <--- says someone without any experience, contradicting the people he asked for their experience, that say otherwise. You can't be helped if you don't want to listen.

Comment: If it connects directly to a 1W speaker it is not "line level".

Comment: Well I'm guessing this, I may be wrong. No need to be rude Marcus Muller, I'm here looking for help and I appreciate it. :) And yes I'm still learning.

Comment: You haven't really looked well at the websites of the people that produce 4066 if you haven't found analog switches with lower Ron: [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/audio.html), [TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/switches-multiplexers/analog-switches-muxes-products.page?keyMatch=analog%2520switch&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything&rec=true#p480=8;32&p2848typ=0.26;21.73&p2848max=0.5;9.5)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks, I will have a look at other switches to fix this in future. Unfortunately I may have to leave as it is for my current project as I have a deadline to present, but I kind of managed to switch things off before the delay through the MCU programme...although that's not the ideal solution.

Comment: And just 1 thing to mention, there was no need to give negative points to my question. I'm learning and that is an actual problem, it's not an absurd or stupid question.

Comment: I explained why I downvoted in my first comment: you're doing something that makes no sense, and had you researched the word "line level", tried out the SSR in isolation (which you "bet" works"), and had described your overall system in the question, it'd be a well-researched, fact-backed question instead of you asking the internet to fix your faulty approach. Quality assurance happens through downvotes here, so don't take it personally! Your next question will surely be better received :)

Comment: Yes, I am definitely wrong in some aspects. The way I always understood line-level is wrong. But I tried a IC switch that was recommended to me and wasn't ideal. And as I had success with mechanical relays before and I had this spare board I thought this would also work. And it does work fine for my project, so it's not something completely non-sense. Of course I did some research online before, but it made complete sense to ask here as I couldn't find anything that would say my approach is wrong. And I got an answer, didn't I?

Comment: Not to mention that there is a capacitor and I thought there was an inductor there (as it looks like one, but it's a fuse). And I know by experience that these things store energy and therefore can delay a signal.

Comment: none of that makes it a reasonably good question in my eyes (and the eyes of another person), but as said, that's the way we all do our quality control here: we look at a question and find out whether we find it is well-researched and well-presented. I did my vote. Others might have voted differently, but so far, they didn't.

Comment: there's no capacitor, and we have discussed this enough. Have a nice day.

Comment: I thought Q by the LEDs was a capacitor. Anyway, thanks and have a nice day you too, sorry to annoy you. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @ArtLyra - "I thought Q by the LEDs was a capacitor." FYI, no, it's a transistor, used to drive the SSR and LED. As *Marcus* said earlier, I cannot see a capacitor anywhere on that PCB in the main photo either.

Comment: @SamGibson I completely forgot Q stands for transistor and for some reason thought it was for capacitors. Sorry about this. Yes, it seems there is nothing there to create a delay...it's definitely the SSR itself and not the board then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green item is a fuse, not an inductor. There is nothing apparent on the board to delay other than what is inside the SSR itself.

You will not get good results with this type of (triac) SSR. You could try to find a compatible MOSFET-output SSR and replace the triac SSRs in your PCB or just start from scratch.

It is better to switch audio before an amplifier than to try to switch at the speakers, if that is what you are doing.

Comment: OP says "line-level" signal, so I guess that's not switching speakers, but switching an amplifier input.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OPs say a lot of things. OP also says signal is attenuated by a few hundred ohms 4066, assuming they hooked it up right (not necessarily a safe assumption) .

Comment: I'm not using an amplifier. This goes straight to 1W speakers. The level is perfect for what I need.
Thanks for letting me know about the fuse. It seems I will have to start from scratch then and I will try MOSFETs.

Comment: @ArtLyra I said "MOSFET-output SSR". You likely will have problems using MOSFETs by themselves at your current level of knowledge.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oh OK! MOSFET-output SSR...I understand it now. Thanks a lot for your help!